# Добавление новых полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выборе файла в поле для загрузки в текстовое поле добавлялась фраза `[ЗагруженноеИзображение(номер)]`, а также появлялось ещё одно поле для загрузки. Я написал код, однако он работает только один раз, т.е. при выборе первого поля добавляется фраза и добавляется новая строка, а при выборе второго поля ничего не происходит. Плюс с помощью атрибута `data-load` отслеживается, чтобы это срабатывало только при выборе пустого поля, а при обновлении данных в уже выбранном ничего не меняется. Вот код:

```
<textarea name="text" id="article_text" required></textarea>
<article class="files">
    <input name="f0" data-load="true" class="image_load" type="file"><br>
</article>
```

А это JS код:

```
//Номер изображения
var imgs = 0;
//Добавление загруженного изображения в текст
$('.image_load').change(function() {
    if($(this).data('load')) {
        $('#article_text').val($('#article_text').val() + '[ЗагруженноеИзображение' + imgs + ']');
        imgs++;
        $(this).data('load', false);
        $('<input type="file" class="image_load" data-load="true" name="f' + imgs + '">').appendTo('.files');
    }
});
```

Почему не работает при следующих загрузках?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при создании нового поля `.image_load` ему не присваивается `.change()` событие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".files").on("change", ".image_load", function() {...});
```

вместо

```
$('.image_load').change(function() {...});
```

Таким образом, обработчик события `change` будет вызываться для всех элементов `.image_load` внутри `.files` - как существующих, так и созданных в дальнейшем.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь всё работает